# commandbar Myreport excel not visible

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I am using microsoft.office.interop.excel to open an excel document.
The document opens correctly but the myReport menu which is a complement installed for excel does not appear in the excel menu bar.
If I open this same document in the classic way, then the menu appears fine.
Do you know that it is the command that would allow me to activate the menu of this complement.

```
execl = new _ExcelWork.Application();
Workbook wb;
Worksheet ws;
wb = execl.Workbooks.Open(fichier.FullName);
```

Answer (score 0):

After several research here is how to counter this behavior.
You have to browse the add list and change the installed property to false then reset it to true.

```
XLS1.AddIns.Installed = false;
XLS1.AddIns.Installed = true;
```